# Three.js move an object according to deltaPosition, in world coordinates

Tags: three.js

I hope this question is answerable. I'm re-implementing the three.js [octree collision demo](https://threejs.org/examples/games_fps.html) in a third-person view. I pass playerCtl, a wireframe sphere (mesh) to the controls, and make the camera its child:

```
controls = new PointerLockControls( playerCtl, document.body )
...
playerCtl.add( camera )
```

This is in contrast to passing the camera to pointerLockControls directly. This part works, and I can rotate my view (camera) around the "head" = playerCtl of the third-person body.

Now I take an instance of a [math Capsule](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/math/Capsule.js) and try to move it around based on velocity and direction of the player. The capsule moves, but relative to its own coords, whereas it should move relative to the world. (and the x-axis is flipped but that's a minor issue)

For example, if I use the controls, turn the playerCtl and go "forward", the playerCtl moves as expected but the capsule (playerCollider) moves in absolute -Z, which is unexpected.

In the demo the collider is moved with a single line:

```
playerCollider.translate( deltaPosition )
```

So how do I adjust that to move the collider in the world coordinates, rather than in local coordinates?

~ * ~ * ~ * ~

A continuation of the same question. Suppose I have a rectangle playerBody that I'd like to move just like the pointerLockControlled object moves. I can use deltaPosition to move it:

```
const deltaPosition = playerVelocity.clone().multiplyScalar( delta )
playerBody.position.x -= deltaPosition.x
playerBody.position.y += deltaPosition.y
playerBody.position.z += deltaPosition.z
```

And that moves erroneously again, in world coordinates whereas I would like it to move in local coordinates. So what do I need to change to achieve that? (I'm currently not rotating anything, unless its rotated by pointerLockControl.)

Comment: I think we're gonna need more info. For example, you say you're copying the FPS Demo, but what are you actually rotating [when the mouse is moved](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/d081c5a3501d272d19375fab1b01fedf9df29b22/examples/games_fps.html#L160-L169)? My guess is that if you're using PointerLockControls, it's rotating the `playerCtl` mesh, but your capsule isn't being rotated, so when you move "forward" (AKA along its internal `-z` axis), the `Mesh` moves after rotations have been applied, while the `Capsule` moves without rotations.

Comment: Hm there was nothing particularly difficult about this task. The issue was that I mixed several ways of doing it together; sticking to just one way, outlined in the collision demo, helped me resolve the issue of moving the collider, and also made the code simpler. The work-in-progress code that works: https://github.com/wasya-co/infiniteshelterjs/blob/2.9.0/src/components/locations3d/ThreePanelDesktop.jsx